# Merge Join over sorted columns instead of Hash Join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

Table **A**

```
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(39), 
    lname varchar (49), 
    ...
)
```

Table **B**

```
(
    id int, 
    city varchar(39), 
    ...
)
```

Both tables are sorted on column `ID`. IDs are simply identities and are populated by auto incremented integers 1 to n.

However, if I input a query e.g.,

```
SELECT * 
FROM A, B 
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

I get a hash join instead of the efficient merge join. How can I enforce the merge join in SQL Server  instead? I don't want to use an index, thus no index-based plans.

Note that I don't want a merge-join with a **sort-enforcer** either, I know that one can hint the planner by rewriting the query to

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
INNER MERGE JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

By the way I'm using SQL Server Express edition. But I can change to any open source DB if the latter supports the query plan that I'm aiming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using the ancient ANSI-89 JOIN syntax? It's long past time to start using the ANSI-92 JOIN Syntax; it has been around for some 28 years now.

Comment: What @Larnu says is not only good advice but also probably the reason that you do not get a merge join: merge join is not available for full joins I think, and the plan probably discards it before noticing that the "filtering condition" is practically an inner join.

Comment: @Larnu because is less typing, and if the join syntax is affecting the optimizer then the SQL team needs to do a lot of rethinking. But I don't believe that.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis thats not true, the syntax won't affect the optimizer. You can try it. It would be strange if it did. You only get a merge join with a sort enforcer which equals to a poor plan!

Comment: *"because is less typing"* with respect, I believe what you mean here is "laziness". That isn't an excuse for using syntax that was superseded 28 years ago. Stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe you are smarted then the SQL Engine :-) you can use hits like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
INNER HASH JOIN B
   ON A.id = B.id
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
INNER MERGE JOIN B
   ON A.id = B.id
```

At least, you can test if the `MERGE` will be really better. And even it is better in this case, does not mean that it will be the best choice always. It can reduce the performance in other cases, so generally it will be better to leave this work to the engine.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it does not work, the planner is introducing the sort enforcer, but that is not necessary as the data is already sorted.

Comment: @Тrex do you have for example a PK on ID on each table?

Comment: if I define PK over the columns in question then the system will create a clustered index, and this is what I want to avoid. My goal is to have a merge join over both relations and not an index scan plan. But I do get your point.

Comment: @Trex The PK can be defined as non-clustered. The point is - you believe the data is ordered but if there is no helper structure (index) to help the engine to extract it in ordered way, you can't avoid the sort stage.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I was hoping to find some sort of option where you can set such that you guarantee the sortedness and hence avoid using index(es) at all.

Comment: That's why you need to create the indexes and leave the engine to do its work. If you have a large amount of data that can be read in a sorted manner the engine may use a sort :-) if there is no guaranty that the data is order and it need to sort, it may decide to choose hash join.